# Startup Project Option in Jetbrains Rider

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm using Jetbrain's Rider. I have two classes in a project. They both have main methods. So I'm getting an erorr saying " Program has more than one entry point". I cannot even find the "Startup Project" (as in Visual Studio) option in Rider. Help me out here.

Answer (score 8):

My answer is probably too late to help the original poster, but this may help future people:

The `Run > Edit Configurations...` menu brings up a dialog where you can manage different configurations.
To run multiple startup projects together, press the **+** button to create a **Compound** configuration and add your projects to it.

Comment: Rider is amazing

Answer (score 1):

You can add next line in `.csproj` (inside `PropertyGroup` tag) with name of the class which should be startup object (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/main-compiler-option)):

```
<StartupObject>MyApplication.Core.Program</StartupObject>
```